# Understanding GCHandle.Alloc pinning in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, prototyping, unsafe-pointers

I inadvertently discovered something that doesn't make sense to me. My questions are in the code comments and below:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 4096)]
public unsafe struct BufItems
{
    public fixed byte Buffer[4096];
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public BufItems Items;
    public int Id;
}

private unsafe void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper();
    wrap.Id = 123;

    fixed(BufItems* ptr = &wrap.Items)
    {
        ptr->Buffer[0] = 99;      // works fine
    }

    // fixed (Wrapper w = wrap)   { /* not possible */ };
    // fixed (Wrapper* w = &wrap) { /* not possible */ };

    // how come I can pin the object this way?
    GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(wrap, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    // what exactly is p pointing to? Wrapper cannot have a pointer.
    IntPtr p = h.AddrOfPinnedObject();
}
```

One other question I have is this: I assume the field `BufItems Items` is created as an object (and hence pinnable), rather than being part of the `wrap` class object instantiation, right? Otherwise pinning would do nothing since `wrap` could be moved by the GC. However, it's a struct, and I thought structs are "embedded" in such cases. What's actually happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's address your questions line-by-line:

> ```
> fixed (Wrapper w = wrap)   { /* not possible */ };
> ```

`fixed` is only allowed to declare a pointer variable. Note however, that pinning (what the `fixed` statement does) is possible on reference types, but not so useful, hence there is nothing in C# to use it (edit: pointers to reference types and non-blittable types will likely be possible in C# 11).

> ```
> fixed (Wrapper* w = &wrap) { /* not possible */ };
> ```

*Wrapper* is a reference type. Allowing you to obtain the pointer to a variable containing the reference to it would in turn allow you to access the actual address of the object, and mess with it horribly. You would be able to cast the pointer to say `object*` and then store any object in the variable, breaking type safety.

> ```
> // how come I can pin the object this way?
> GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(wrap, GCHandleType.Pinned);
> ```

As I already said, instance pinning is possible in .NET, but not syntactically in C#. You can pin any blittable type (without reference fields) with this method. Pinning the object guarantees that its location on the heap won't change.

> ```
> // what exactly is p pointing to? Wrapper cannot have a pointer.
> IntPtr p = h.AddrOfPinnedObject();
> ```

Maybe it will be better to illustrate it on this code:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
fixed(int* p = arr) { ... }
fixed(int* p = &arr[0]) { ... }
```

The two lines are compiled to exactly same CIL (for performance), but the first line can be also achieved by using *GCHandle* the same way you did. *AddrOfPinnedObject* returns the pointer to the first field in the object, the same as in `fixed(BufItems* ptr = &wrap.Items)`.

*BufItems* is a value type, therefore the *Items* field does not contain a reference, but the actual fixed array, together with the int following it.

Comment: Thanks much! So, when I am pinning (via `fixed`) the `BufItems Items` field, then .Net is actually pinning `wrap`? As you said, the struct is a value type.

Comment: @IamIC Yes, it has to pin the whole instance. CLR is clever enough to determine the whole object from an address of its field.

Comment: I figured there was something different happening to what the code explicitly states. The outcome is fine, but it's a little disappointing how it's achieved.